# XPath - array to string conversion error

Tags: xml, xpath, simplexml, php

I'm using `simplexml_load_string` to load some XML:

```
$xml = "<payment><cardHolderName><![CDATA[John Smith]]></cardHolderName></payment>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

How can I then access the cardHolderName (John Smith) using xpath? I've tried:

```
$name = $xml->xpath('/payment/cardHolderName');
echo $name;
```

But the value is empty and I get a warning:

> Array to string conversion

Same result with all of these xpaths:

```
'/payment/cardHolderName'
'/payment/cardHolderName[1]'
'/payment/cardHolderName/text()'
'/payment/cardHolderName[1]/text()'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the code that gives you this warning?

Comment: @fab I've updated my question to include the code.

Comment: The xpath() method always returns an array with alll matched nodes. You can't use an xpath with it that returns anything else than nodes.

Comment: Just FYI: `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` has no support for the xpath function `text()`. You can only query elements and attributes with simplexml xpath.

Answer (score 2):

see if this works for you:

```
$name = $order->xpath('/payment/cardHolderName');
echo $name[0];
```

Comment: It does, thank you. I should've mentioned that I'd already worked that out, but I wondered why it won't work with xpath alone.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath query isn't quite right, in this context `$xml` represents your root element ("payment") so you would refer to the name with

```
$order->xpath('cardHolderName');
```

That said, AFAIK simplexml has less than stellar XPath support. You 'd be doing this much easier with `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` instead, which works as you 'd expect.

Comment: Sorry, that was in fact a typo when transferring the code. I still get the same result, so I'll look into DOMDocument and DOMXpath.